# How would one find the "coastline" of an object stored in a 2D list using Python?

Tags: python, list, 2d, flood-fill

I'm trying to create a survival roguelike game using Python and the CMD terminal.
I have a 2 dimensional list that contains a continent and some separate islands.
What I need is to find the outline of each object - like so:

```
#########     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
#.......#     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
#.###...#     [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
#.# #...#     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
#.###...##    [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
##.......#    [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 #########    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

   island             data
```

where "#" is the coastline, "." is land and " " is water.
I think it's possible to somehow use a flood-fill algorithm to find the edges of the continent/islands, but I have no idea how flood-fill algorithms are implemented in Python or how to make one.

### Thanks.

EDIT 1:

My plan is to create "beach" areas, requiring me to track coastlines.
An area in game is a 2D list, and **right now** it can be represented by 0 (false/water) and 1 (true/land). I want to create 2 (beach).

```
 area = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
         [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
         [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]] # This is right now.
```

compared to

```
area = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [0,2,0,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0],
        [0,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0]] # This where I want to be
```

(these weren't full maps)

Comment: can you post this 2d list as valid python? is `data` a 2d list where `#` is replaced by `1`, `.` and `""` by `0`? so what is it that you expect?

Comment: ahh... sorry. i'll edit and elaborate

Comment: Also, I think I figured it out on my own - run through the land tiles and turn any touching water to beach tiles. Whoops.